# $h^*(T)=\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \{\sup h^*(T,\alpha):\operatorname{diam}(\alpha)<\epsilon\}$

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, entropy, ergodic-theory

$\newcommand{\diam}{\operatorname{diam}}$I have the following theorem:

> Let $X$ be a compact metric space, $T:X \to X$ be continuous  and $(\alpha_n)$ be a set of open covers such that $\diam(\alpha_n)\to 0.$ Then 
>   $$h^*(T)=\lim_{n \to \infty} h^*(T ,\alpha_n).$$

From this, I want to conclude:

> $$h^*(T)=\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \{\sup h^*(T,\alpha):\diam(\alpha)<\epsilon\}$$

Here, $h^*(T,\alpha)$ is the entropy of $T$ with respect to $\alpha$ and  $h^*(T)=\sup\{h^*(T,\alpha):\alpha \text{ is an open cover} \}.$

**My attempt:**

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given and let $(\alpha_n)$ be an open cover such that $\diam(\alpha_n)=\frac{1}{n}. $ Then there exists $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\diam(\alpha_n)=\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$$ for all $n \geq n_0.$ Thus, $$\sup\{ h^*(T,\alpha):\diam(\alpha)
<\epsilon\} \geq h^*(T,\alpha_n)$$ for all $n \geq n_0.$ It follows that 
$$h^*(T)\geq\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \{\sup h^*(T,\alpha):\diam(\alpha)<\epsilon\}\geq \lim_{n \to \infty}h^*(T,\alpha_n)=h^*(T).$$

> Is the above argument correct?

Comment: With \textrm{diam} or \mathrm{diam} you don't automatically get proper spacing in things like $A \operatorname{diam} B$ or $A\operatorname{diam}(B),$ and instead you see $A\textrm{diam}B$ or $A\textrm{diam}(B).$ I edited accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you. I learned something new today :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your argument is correct.